# How can a user update another user's tag?

Tags: quickblox

I am designing an app where a user adds another user to a group. I am implementing groups with tags. So one user has to change another users tags.

From the documentation, I can deduce that only the user can update its own information. So how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You're right - only user can update own tags.

You can do it using CustomObjects API http://quickblox.com/developers/Custom_Objects

For example - create Group entity and use it for this purpose.

CustomObjects API has Permissions API - http://quickblox.com/developers/Custom_Objects#Permissions

So you can set who can update your records